# How to use/cast a reference to "this" in an abstract class' member function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino, this, abstract-class

The following code works great...

```
 class Printable { public:
   virtual size_t printTo(Print& p) const = 0;
 };

class Printer : public Printable { public:

  size_t printTo(Print& p) const {
   return p.print("I am a printer");
  }
};

Printer pp;

void loop() { Serial.println(pp); }
```

> `I am a printer` ....

However, if I try to use this new found printability within a public member function of `Printer`..

```
void print() { Serial.println(this); }
```

it bricks...

```
 error: call of overloaded 'println(Printer* const)' is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
  size_t Print::println(char) <near match>
  note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Printer* const' to 'char'
  size_t Print::println(unsigned char, int) <near match>
  note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Printer* const' to 'unsigned char'
  size_t Print::println(int, int) <near match>
  note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Printer* const' to 'int'
```

etc, etc... But why isn't the compiler finding the "candidate" (in that same `Print` header, of which `Serial` is a subclass of)...

```
size_t println(const Printable&);
```

or even

```
size_t println(void);
```

I've tried every cast unto `this` I could evoke, without any magic.   Is it simply not possible to invoke abstract class functions with `this`?

For all those clamoring for a [compilable example... here you are](https://gist.github.com/mralexgray/6f436a0ff7599c6e5d46bd136c41ccd1).

Comment: Where is the definition of println? Please provide a real MCVE.

Comment: _"Is it simply not possible to invoke abstract class functions with `this`?"_ No, it's perfectly possible. Please add a [MCVE] that shows you can't actually.

Comment: The compiler seems to be saying unambiguously that you haven't declared any overload of `println` that takes a pointer to `Printer` as an argument.

Comment: You have been around SO long enough to know the importance of posting an MCVE. We shouldn't even have to ask.

Comment: The code ***is*** "MCVE", **IF** you have the `Arduino` toolchain installed... hence the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated that

```
void loop() { Serial.println(pp); }
```

works, I am going to venture a guess that you need:

```
void print() { Serial.println(*this); }
                           // ^^ Need * before "this"
```

`this` is a pointer to the current object. `*this` is the object it points to.

Comment: I think you are right...  In my rush to create an "acceptable" code example... I tried with _just such a pointer_, and _voila_! Let me double check in the actual Arduino environment.. but I think you're on the money. :-)